# C# MVC Controller ActionResult query takes a long time to load when there are a lot of records

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have an ActionResult to get Parts that relate to the Vendor Selected. When there is a large amount of parts to get it takes a long time to load. In testing the SQL side it has items that probably do not need to be there. Once removed from the query it is fine and retrieves at a good speed. My question is what in the Controller Code is adding this to the query and slowing it down.

Here is my controller code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add (Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            RFQViewModel r = new RFQViewModel();
            GeneralEntities cn = new GeneralEntities();
            List<PartsViewModel> Apart = new List<PartsViewModel>();
            r.selectedParts = db.VendorsMaterialMap.Where(a => a.VendorId == id).Select(a => a.Material.ToString()).ToArray();
            Apart = db.Parts.Where(k => r.selectedParts.Contains(k.Material.ToString())).Select(v => new PartsViewModel
            {
                Material = v.Material,
                PartNumber = v.PartNumber,
                VendorReference = v.VendorReference,
                PartImage = v.PartImage,
                UnitOfMeasure = v.UnitOfMeasure
            }).ToList();
            r.partitem = Apart;
            r.RFQId = Guid.NewGuid();
            r.vendor = db.Vendors.Where(d => d.VendorId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            var Check = db.RFQs.Where(k => k.VendorId == id).OrderByDescending(K => K.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();
            if (Check != null)
            {
                var diff = (System.DateTime.Now - Check.RequestDate).Value;
                var days = diff.Days;
                if (days < 7)
                {
                    ViewBag.msg = "You already created order for This vendor  before... <a href='/RFQ/Details/ " + Check.RFQId + "'>Click here</a>";
                }
            }
            return View(r);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

On the SQL side this is the query that is running (I have taken the data out but 1):

```
  SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Material] AS [Material], 
[Extent1].[PartNumber] AS [PartNumber], 
[Extent1].[VendorReference] AS [VendorReference], 
[Extent1].[PartImage] AS [PartImage], 
[Extent1].[UnitOfMeasure] AS [UnitOfMeasure]
FROM [dbo].[Parts] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (LOWER( CAST( [Extent1].[Material] AS nvarchar(max))) IN (N'95647db7-00c4-e911-bb01-001c4208b889' 
   <---- Other Retrieved Data ------>
)) AND (LOWER( CAST( [Extent1].[Material] AS nvarchar(max))) IS NOT NULL)
```

If I Remove the LOWER and Change the nvarchar(max) to nvarchar(50). The query comes back fast no matter how many record i pull. So What in the above Controller Code is making a GUID nvarchar(max) and taking it to Lower?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does the columns in actual database table have nvarchar(max) datatype?

Comment: No it is set to uniqueidentifier. The only piece of data that has nvarchar(max) that is in the query is PartImage. Which i am going to change because it doesn't need to be. It is only the name of the image IE- thisImageExists.jpg. However it doesn't bring the Image in this query anyway, just the uniqueidentifier of the matching record.

Comment: `k.Material.ToString()` is causing the SQL to cast the column value to nvarchar(max). Is it possible for you to not use ToString in code?

Comment: I will give it a try and see what happens..

Comment: I tried to take it out but it does not like it. Maybe if it were coded out differently I may be able to take it out. Not sure how i would re-code it differently..

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by `it does not like it.` and also I don't have complete idea about your code. Based on whatever code you have shared, following is my suggestion. if type of `r.selectedParts` is `string[]` then change it to `Guid[]`. Change `Select(a => a.Material.ToString())` to `Select(a => a.Material)`. Change `r.selectedParts.Contains(k.Material.ToString()))` to `r.selectedParts.Contains(k.Material))`.

Comment: Got it. I did not change the string[ ] to Guid[ ]. That was what was giving me the issue. It must have been that as well for the LOWER. It is no longer there either. And populates quickly. Thank you for your help!